# R studio error occured while writing the preprocessing data code

Tags: r

i am getting the following error while writing the code in Rstudio

```
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"dataset$Age = ifelse(is.na(dataset$Age),
                 ave(dataset$Age, FUN = fuction(x) mean"
>                      dataset$Age)
Error: unexpected ')' in "                     dataset$Age)"
```

the code is as follows

```
dataset = read.csv('Data.csv')
dataset$Age = ifelse(is.na(dataset$Age),
                 ave(dataset$Age, FUN = fuction(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)),
                 dataset$Age)
```

any help would be great.

Answer (score 3):

You wrote fuction instead of fu**n**ction.

```
dataset = list()
dataset[["Age"]] = c(10,20,30,40,50, NA)

ifelse(is.na(dataset$Age),
       ave(dataset$Age, FUN = function(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)),
       dataset$Age)

[1] 10 20 30 40 50 30
```